# Name of anti pattern for complexity

Tags: architecture, anti-patterns

Is there a standard anti-pattern or something that could be referenced, to argue that when a system reaches a given complexity it will become unmaintainable and will collapse?

Something like systems are never finished they are just abandoned, just a more serious version.

Comment: Could be migrated to Programmers maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion: the Lava Flow [description](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/lava-flow). It isn't exactly what you're talking about, but it might, with a longer description of the project.

I've personally encountered this monster on several big scale projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think technical debt is the term you are looking for.
When your project's technical debt is too high, your project becomes overly complex and even small changes have an high impact (and thus make it unmaintainable).

You can read about the [definition of technical debt](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html) here.